# Android Programming: Background color not fully covering fragments

Tags: android, css, xml, background, android-linearlayout

So I'm in the middle of creating my first 'real' application in Android.

I'm having a problem with my background color as it not stretches the whole background, I'm still having a box-like grey lines around my app.

I was kind of worried because on the simulator, it shows it like it should be, but on my emulator(s, i tried multiple to check), it shows the following (see pic 2):
Preview:
[image]

emulator:
[image]

**Layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d8edc2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSenderName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSenderEmail" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Subject"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSenderSubject" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Message"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSenderMessage" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send message"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Check the layout your `Fragment` container is in.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but could you be more specific? I'm using the default navigation drawer and it is spread over multiple layout files. `activity_main, app_bar_main, content_main` and `nav_header_main`. And what would I be looking for if I manage to find the correct layout my `Fragment` is on contained in?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that default project, but you're looking for the `ViewGroup` - probably a `FrameLayout` - that the `Fragment`s get transacted into. In your code, you probably have something like `getFragmentManager().replace(...)`. You wanna find the `ViewGroup` that has the ID that is passed as the first argument in that call.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike M. , in the `content_main.xml` -file, I found out that there were all sorts of paddings which were set on `16dp`. I set them on `0dp` (because removing them gave build errors) and now my background is fully covered in the emulator! Thanks again, I did not now that the `fragments` were so dependent of the `main activity` it's running in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I guess is the Activity of layout problem.You check your layout XML files, check to see if there is the following code:

```html
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```